# How to redirect GAE custom domain to www url?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname

I have hosted my application in Google App Engine. Now I can able to access my app using `example.com` and as well as `www.example.com`. Now I want to redirect every request to `www.example.com`. How to perform this redirection?

Comment: FYI: you can connect your app to naked domain without www by using new developers console.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with django or appengine. Look into your domain hosting and find out how to change Cname record (domain forwarding. )

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the domain using [Google Apps for Work](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) then you can do so from **Admin Console > Domains > Change redirect** and then follow the instructions. Either case as it's already mentioned you will have to change/update the CNAME records from your domain provider.